# Is it possible to pre-allocate array for matrix factorization?

Tags: julia

My question is instead of `F = svd(A)`, can one first allocate an appropriate memory for an SVD structure, and then do `F .= svd(A)` ?

What I had in mind is something like the following:

```
function main()
    F = Vector{SVD}(undef,10)
    # how to preallocate F?
    test(F)
end

function test(F::Vector{SVD})
    for i in 1:10
        F .= svd(rand(3,3))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code almost works. But what you probably wanted was this:

```
using LinearAlgebra

function main()
    F = Vector{SVD}(undef, 10)
    test(F)
end

function test(F::Vector{SVD})
    for i in 1:10
        F[i] = svd(rand(3, 3))
    end
    return F
end
```

The line that you had in the `for` loop was this:

```
F .= svd(rand(3,3))
```

which does the same operation on every loop, since you were not indexing into `F`. In particular, this operation was trying to broadcast a single `SVD` object into all the fields of `F` on each iteration of the loop. (And that broadcast operation failed because by default `struct`s are treated as iterable objects with a `length` method, but `SVD` does not have a `length` method.)

However, I would recommend against pre-allocating a vector in this situation. First, let's look at the type of `F`:

```
julia> typeof(Vector{SVD}(undef, 10))
Array{SVD,1}
```

The problem with this vector is that it is parameterized by an abstract type. There is a [section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-abstract-container) in the Performance Tips chapter of the manual that advises against this. `SVD` is an abstract type because the types of its parameters have not been specified. To make it concrete, you need to specify the types of the parameters, like this:

```
julia> SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}
SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}

julia> Vector{SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}(undef, 2)
2-element Array{SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}},1}:
 #undef
 #undef
```

As you can see, it is difficult to correctly specify the concrete type when you are working with complicated types like `SVD`. Additionally, if you do so, your code will not be as generic as it could be.

A better approach for a problem like this is to use mapping, broadcasting, or a list comprehension. Then the correct output type will automatically be inferred. Here are some examples:

#### List comprehension

```
julia> [svd(rand(3, 3)) for _ in 1:2]
2-element Array{SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}},1}:
 SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}([-0.6357040496635746 -0.2941425771794837 -0.7136949667270628; -0.45459999623274916 -0.6045700314848496 0.654090147040599; -0.6238743500629883 0.7402534845042064 0.2506104028424691], [1.4535849689665463, 0.7212190827260345, 0.05010669163393896], [-0.5975505057447164 -0.588792736048385 -0.5442945039782142; 0.7619724725128861 -0.6283345569895092 -0.15682358121595258; -0.2496624605679292 -0.5084474392397449 0.8241054891903787])
 SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}([-0.5593632049776268 0.654338345992878 -0.5088753618327984; -0.6687620652652163 -0.7189576326033171 -0.18936003428293915; -0.4897653570633183 0.23439550227070827 0.8397551092645418], [1.8461274187259178, 0.21226179692488983, 0.14194607536315287], [-0.29089551972856004 -0.7086270946133293 -0.6428276887173754; -0.9203610429640889 0.023709029028269546 0.390350397126212; 0.2613720474647311 -0.7051847436823973 0.6590896221923739])
```

#### Map

```
julia> map(_ -> svd(rand(3, 3)), 1:2)
2-element Array{SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}},1}:
 SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}([-0.5807809149601634 0.5635242755434755 0.5874809951745127; -0.6884131975465821 0.0451903888051729 -0.7239095925620322; -0.43448912329507794 -0.8248625459025509 0.3616918330643316], [1.488618654040125, 0.4122166626927311, 0.004235624485479941], [-0.6721098925787947 -0.2684664121709399 -0.6900681689759235; -0.7384292974335966 0.31185073633575333 0.5978890289498324; -0.05468514413847799 -0.9114136842196914 0.4078414290231468])
 SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}([-0.3677873424759118 0.8090638526628051 -0.4584191892023337; -0.43071684640222546 -0.5851169278783189 -0.6871107472129654; -0.8241452960126802 -0.055261768200600137 0.5636760310989947], [1.6862363968739773, 0.5899255050748418, 0.24246688716190598], [-0.3751742784957875 -0.7172409091515735 -0.5872050229643736; 0.8600668700980193 -0.505618838823938 0.06807766730822862; -0.3457300098559026 -0.4794945964927631 0.8065703268899])
```

#### Broadcasting

```
julia> g = (rand(3, 3) for _ in 1:2)
Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},var"#17#18"}(var"#17#18"(), 1:2)

julia> svd.(g)
2-element Array{SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}},1}:
 SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}([-0.7988295268840152 0.5443221484534134 -0.256095266807727; -0.5436890668169485 -0.8354777569473182 -0.0798693700362902; -0.257436566171119 0.07543418554831638 0.963346302244777], [1.8188722412547844, 0.3934389096422389, 0.2020398396772306], [-0.7147404794808727 -0.37763644211761316 -0.5886737335538281; -0.6944558966482991 0.4830041206449164 0.5333273169925189; -0.08292800854873916 -0.7899985677359054 0.607474450798845])
 SVD{Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,2}}([-0.5910620103531503 0.3599866268397522 0.7218416228050514; -0.7367495542691711 0.12340124384185132 -0.664809918173956; -0.3283988340440176 -0.9247603805931685 0.1922821996018057], [1.826019614357666, 0.5333148215847028, 0.11639139812894106], [-0.6415954756495915 -0.6888196183142843 -0.33746522643279503; -0.5845558664639438 0.7239484700883465 -0.3663236978948133; -0.4966383841474222 0.037764349353666515 0.8671356118331964])
```

Furthermore, mapping, broadcasting, and list comprehensions should be just as efficient as pre-allocating the vector. If you're doing a simple mapping, then it's usually easier and more readable to use mapping, broadcasting, or list comprehensions. Pre-allocating vectors is a tool I reserve for writing custom algorithms from scratch.

A final note. In most cases, type parameters are considered an *implementation detail* and are not a part of the public API for a type. As such, it's best to use generic programming approaches that do not rely on fixing the types for type parameters. Of course there are some exceptions to this rule of thumb, like `Array{T,N}` and `Dict{K,V}`.

Answer (score 4):

There's a differnent way of preallocation -- you can reuse the input array by always overwriting it, with both the `rand` call and `svd`'s internal needs:

```
function test!(F::Vector{SVD})
    A = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 3, 3)
    for i in 1:10
        rand!(A)
        F[i] = svd!(A)
    end
end
```

Cameron's advice still holds. I'd probably use something like

```
function test()
    A = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 3, 3)
    return map(1:10) do i
        svd!(rand!(A))
    end
end
```

given that the number of loops seems not be the critical part.